# cannot resolve method getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using Android Studios, however, I am unable to add the below two methods as it says that it cannot resolve them.

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Detail")
```

;

Comment: Are you using an AppCompatActivity?

Comment: No am using public class First extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Comment: #Maddle_J it is the problem. Check the answer below.

Comment: Thanks it has now worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that **you are not extending** the [`AppCompatActivity`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html):

Change:

```
 public class First extends FragmentActivity
```

with:

```
 public class First extends AppCompatActivity
```

As you can check in the doc the [`getSupportActionBar()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()) method depends on the `AppCompatActivity.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in onCreate() method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
setTitle("Detail");
```

Comment: I am using it inside the onCreate method, however, it says that it cannot resolve getsupportAction().serDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: now it says that it cannot resolve method   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);